# Slider in jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have this site with a slide on the Home page:

http://eventos.dac-proiect.ro/

This is my script:

```
    (function($) {

   var firstImage = $('#slider-content .slider-img:first').index();
   var lastImage = $('#slider-content .slider-img:last').index();

   var currentImage = firstImage
   var nextImage = firstImage + 1
   var prevImage = lastImage

   var sliderImages = $('#slider-content .slider-img');
   var sliderContent = $('#slider-content');

   var sliderImageWidth = parseFloat(sliderImages.eq(0).css('width'));

   $('#button-next').click(function(e) {
       nextImage = currentImage == lastImage ? firstImage : currentImage + 1;
       sliderContent.animate({ "left": -nextImage * sliderImageWidth });
       currentImage = nextImage;
       e.preventDefault();   
   });
   $('#button-prev').click(function(e) {
       prevImage = currentImage == firstImage ? lastImage : currentImage - 1;
       sliderContent.animate({ "left": -prevImage * sliderImageWidth });
       currentImage = prevImage;
       e.preventDefault();  
   });
})(jQuery);
```

When you press the arrow does not change the images...in the local work.

This is code HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
        <img id="button-prev" src="http://eventos.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/themes/eventos/images/left.jpg">

        <div class="slider-mask">
        <div id="slider-content">
            <div class="slider-img">
                <img src="http://eventos.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/themes/eventos/images/2.jpg" alt="Flamingo" />

            </div>
            <div class="slider-img">
                <img src="http://eventos.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/themes/eventos/images/3.jpg" alt="Flamingo" />

            </div>


            </div>
        </div>

        <img id="button-next" src="http://eventos.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/themes/eventos/images/right.jpg">
    </div>
```

This is code CSS:

```
#slider {
    width: 1003px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative; 
}

.slider-img {
    margin:0; 
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.caption  {
    color:#DC6804; 
    padding:5px 10px 10px 10px; 
    margin:0; 
    font-family:Verdana; 
    text-transform:uppercase; 
    font-size:12px;
}

.slider-mask {
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
}   

#button-prev {
    position: absolute;
    top: 180px;
    cursor: pointer;
    left: -45px;
}

#button-next {
    position: absolute;
    top: 180px;
    cursor: pointer;
    right: -45px;
}

/* 
adjust #slider-content width as needed 
width = image width * image count
width = 600px * 3 = 1800px 
*/
#slider-content {
    width: 19800px;
    position: relative;
}
```

I do not understand why I do not work ... I use a theme built from 0 in wordpress

This is code for declaring script in Functions.php

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_script_method');

function my_script_method()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('script', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/slider/js/jquery-slider.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_enqueue_style('script-style',  get_template_directory_uri().'/js/slider/css/style.css');

}
```

Can you please help me with this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're setting the width before the elements are displayed, so the width is calculated as 0.

Comment: And how should it be?

Comment: Kinda a little difficult to debug without being able to manipulate the code, but from what I can tell, your javascript is executing before your images are loaded. Try encapsulating your code into a document ready call, like `(function($) { $(function() { /* execute code here */ }); })(jQuery)`

Comment: Unfortunately no effect

Comment: There's a syntax error in there.

Comment: I solved the first error but it appeared that one ... and not know how to solve

Comment: You just need to close your document ready call, see: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myjxPP

Comment: Now the code has no errors but still does not work

Comment: Hmm I'm not really sure without playing with the code myself. Could you just set the slide width as 1003?

Comment: No, your variable: `var sliderImageWidth = 1003`